# post forms in mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have written the following code in my view and when user click on image button the form should be submitted but it is not submitting

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Resumename", "Resumewizard", 
  FormMethod.Post, new { name = "Resumetitle",OnLoad="Error();"})){ %>
  <%=Html.Label("Step 1.Resume Name")%><br />
  <%=Html.Label("Please Enter Resume Name,Job Title and Objective")%><br />
  <%=Html.Label("Resume Name")%><br />
  <%=Html.TextBox("ResTitle")%><br />
  <%=Html.Label("Desired Job Title/Position")%><br />
  <%=Html.TextBox("DesPos")%><br />
  <%=Html.Label("Objective")%><br />
  <%=Html.TextArea("ResObjective")%><br />
  <% string str = ViewData["Errormsg"].ToString(); %>
  <div id="msgblock">
   <%=Html.Label(str)%>
   <%=Html.Hidden("error", ViewData["Errormsg"])%>
   <%=Html.Hidden("resumeid",ViewData["resumeid"])%>
  </div>
  <input id="SaveForwardButton" type="image" 
   src="../../Content/img/buttons/SaveForwardButton.gif" />
<% } %>
```

Comment: Given how poorly formed your output HTML is, it wouldn't surprise me if your page was invalid, and was thus simply not parsing correctly.  I suggest validating the output html against the W3C validator and looking for problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button `type` is set to `image`. I think you should change it to `submit`.

Comment: image buttons submit as well.

Comment: it is not posting the form what can i do

Comment: You keep saying it is not posting. What do you mean by that? Do you mean the browser resolutely does not send any data to the server? Does the server receive the request but does not handle it the way you want?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I do it with jQuery, something like below:

```
<%using (Html.BeginForm("Resumename", "Resumewizard", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "Resumetitle",OnLoad="Error();"}))
          {%>
          <%=Html.Label("Step 1.Resume Name")%><br />
         <%=Html.Label("Please Enter Resume Name,Job Title and Objective")%><br />
         <%=Html.Label("Resume Name")%><br />
        <%=Html.TextBox("ResTitle")%><br />
        <%=Html.Label("Desired Job Title/Position")%><br />
        <%=Html.TextBox("DesPos")%><br />
        <%=Html.Label("Objective")%><br />
        <%=Html.TextArea("ResObjective")%><br />
        <%  string str = ViewData["Errormsg"].ToString();
          %>
       <div id="msgblock">
       <%=Html.Label(str)%>
       <%=Html.Hidden("error", ViewData["Errormsg"])%>
       <%=Html.Hidden("resumeid",ViewData["resumeid"])%>
       </div>
       <img class="SaveForwardButton" src="../../Content/img/buttons/SaveForwardButton.gif" />

       <script type="text/javascript">
       $(".SaveForwardButton").click(function () {
          $(this).parents("form").trigger("submit");
       });
       </script>

<% }%>
```

Normally I would declare this in my main .js file and apply the submit class to whatever element I like.

Comment: for the record, this approach is ok, but not great practice to assume the user has JavaScript. Setting up an image input as the asker did is good, then if you want to enhance it you can use JQuery for that afterwards - see "progressive enhancement".